# Do digital multimeters work the same in vacuum?

Tags: measurement, multimeter, harsh-environment

We want to use a [RS14 Handheld Digital Multimeter](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://docs.rs-online.com/f0d7/A700000007105463.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiip7PInpmDAxWL76QKHTYXAp4QFnoECBAQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0-Doq2EoHTbOGQrso0EsMa) inside a glovebox and therefore we submit it to vacuum (0.1 bar) to come in and out of it, and to inert N2 atmosphere once it is inside the box.

Does anybody know if submitting a digital multimeter sequentially to these changes in pressure and atmosphere could influence their operation or measuring capabilities in any way?

Comment: I'd be more concerned about temperature changes than vacuum and inert atmosphere.  Expanding gas cools things fast.

Comment: low density air does not convect heat away as quickly, vacuum not at all. Beware power rating of current shunts. The standard environmental rating of many pieces of equipmemt only goes down to pressurised freight levels.

Comment: Out of curiosity I googled a bit. Seems Electrolytic caps and even some Tantals may react to harsh pressure changes. I assume all hermetically sealed components that aren't MilSpec or even NASA spec might have problems with that. 
If you measure big currents, heat dissipation may also be an issue, since all the components are rated in a ventilated environment.

Comment: Some MEMS oscillators (used in a lot of digital electronics) can behave strangely when exposed to certain atmospheres; there was a thing a while ago about iphones crashing when exposed to too much helium. Unsure if vacuum would do anything to them; pretty sure pure nitrogen wouldn't.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by glovebox. In the UK, a glovebox is a compartment in a car on the passenger side hence, my question.

Comment: @Andyaka the same term seems to be used interchangeably between the car compartment and [a laboratory enclosure like this](https://www.coleparmer.co.uk/c/glove-boxes) in both the US and UK.

Comment: @Andyaka I think it could be something like [Laboratory Glove Box](https://www.ossila.com/collections/glove-box) which says ``Ideal for many inert atmosphere applications, from air sensitive experiments to handling hazardous materials and chemicals. ``

Comment: At £37.90 (inc. VAT) you might as well just try putting it in the glovebox, taking it out, and seeing if the readings are still good enough - presumably the nitrogen atmosphere is going to be at atmospheric pressure and the partial vacuum is just to rinse out the air a bit. You might want to take the battery cover off in case the multimeter has gaskets to keep water splashes out. IMO.